# How to forward the data to another JSP page upon submit data to a link in a JSP page using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, jsp

I have a URL link in the JSP form page. Once submit the form, all the data will submitted and call to the URL link. How can I forward those data that i submit to the URL link to another JSP page.

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function response() {
            $.ajax({
                url         : "http://xxxxx/sendmsg",
                data        : {
                    "username" : msg_user,
                    "recipient" : msg_recipient,
                    "sender" : msg_sender,
                    "content" : msg_content
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#ajaxgetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
                },
                error: function(data, err) {
                        console.error(err);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://xxxxx/sendmsg" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input name=" msg_user" type="text"/><br>
        <input name="msg_recipient" type="text"/><br>
        <input name="msg_sender" type="text"/><br>
        <input name="msg_content" type="text"/><br>
        <button type="submit" style="display: none;">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
</body>
```

I'm able to submit the form and call to URL link. But unfortunately, there's only show successful response for the message without those detail of form we have submit previously.

[image: Output Get]

Below showing what's the ideal output I wish to get. 
[image: Ideal Output]

Is there anyone who able to give my guide on how should I proceed or continue with it?

Comment: Do you know how to use a servlet and jstl? If you submit the form to a servlet, then you can forward the data to another jsp page and access those values using jstl. If any of this sounds new to you I can elaborate. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330890/how-to-pass-values-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp-to-update-database) is a post similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: @HowardCombs I doesn't want to use servlet and jstl. for later stage I need to integrate it with my other project using J2EE . Is there any others way? BTW, it's kinda new to me too.

Comment: Post the code of page which is not displaying the value's, Meaning show us the code of redirected page.

Comment: @susu If I understand right, you do an AJAX call, and if that ajax call is successful, you want to display what was submitted on the form, redirect to a separate jsp page and also display what was submitted on the form on that page?

Comment: @HowardCombs yes. It's what i wish to do. But there's one problem i'm facing which is i'm linking the form with URL too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I felt it would be worth trying.

```js
function response() {
  $.ajax({

    var msg_user = $('form input[name=msg_user]').val();
    var msg_recipient = $('form input[name=msg_recipient]').val();
    var msg_sender = $('form input[name=msg_sender]').val();
    var msg_content = $('form input[name=msg_content]').val();


    url: "http://xxxxx/sendmsg",
      data: {
        "username": msg_user,
        "recipient": msg_recipient,
        "sender": msg_sender,
        "content": msg_content
      },
      success: function(data) {

        var response = "Username: " + msg_user + "<br>" +
          "Recipient: " + msg_recipient + "<br>" +
          "Sender:" + msg_sender + "<br>" +
          "Content: " + msg_content;


        $('#ajaxgetUserServletResponse').text(response);
      },
      error: function(data, err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's wont work for me... It's mentioning [SyntaxError: missing : after property id of msg_user] .